# rpm: list unnecessary dependencies like dpkg-shlibdeps does?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, dpkg

When building a .deb package [dpkg-shlibdeps](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dpkg-dev/dpkg-shlibdeps.1.en.html) is (or can be) invoked to automatically add dependencies on libraries used by your package.

It produces useful output like:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: package could avoid a useless dependency if ./foo.so were not linked against libboost_regex.so.1.62.0 (they use none of the library's symbols)
```

Is there an equivalent feature for rpm? or a pre-existing platform neutral tool?

Comment: What is the magic inside dpkg-shlibdeps used to detect this? Perhaps its worth pulling out into a platform neutral tool which then could be invoked by RPM?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no :)

rpmbuild add .so dependencies automatically.

You can check that `rpm -qR bash` list this requirements:

```
...
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
...
```

but as you can see in sources: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/bash/blob/master/f/bash.spec there is no such line like:

```
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)
```

This works for .so libraries, Perl modules and very recently in Fedora for Python modules. Any other library has to be added manually to spec file.

However, those dependencies are calculated on linked libraries, if you link to the library, but do not use any symbol from that library then I am afraid that RPM world does not have any utility to detect this useless dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer.

RPM does not support this directly.
RPM finds what a package requires and provides through the scripts `find-requires` and `find-provides`, normally in /usr/lib/rpm.

These are run as follows:

```
>find . | /usr/lib/rpm/find-provides
libfoobar.so.1()(64bit)

>find . | /usr/lib/rpm/find-requires
libasound.so.2()(64bit)
libboost_atomic-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
libboost_chrono-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
libboost_regex-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
```

There is also a compiled program /usr/lib/rpm/elfdeps that works the same way. rpmbuild seems to use this rather than the scripts.

See http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html (note the real scripts are not much like the example there).

The remaining part of the question is how does dpkg-shlibdeps do it?
I will add this when I find time to look into it if no-one gets there first.

Comment: The man page you link to in the question explains the mechanics of `dpkg-shlibdeps` in some detail.